# Launching On-Screen Keyboard

Tags: windows-7, on-screen-keyboard

I cannot run `osk` or `osk.exe` to launch my on-screen keyboard. I checked my System32 folder and it appears I have all the necessary dependencies:

- `ADVAPI32.DLL`
- `COMCTL32.DLL`
- `COMDLG32.DLL`
- `GDI32.DLL`
- `KERNEL32.DLL`
- `MSSWCH.DLL`
- `MSVCRT.DLL`
- `NTDLL.DLL`
- `OLE32.DLL`
- `OSK.EXE`
- `RPCRT4.DLL`
- `SHELL32.DLL`
- `SHLWAPI.DLL`
- `USER32.DLL`
- `WINMM.DLL`

Note: I did a custom Windows 7 install (RT Se7en Lite) in which I disabled Ease of Access features, but I kept the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help, but here is the list of ALL the Dynamic Link Libraries that OSK.exe accesses when it is launched. I removed the ones you mentioned in your question.

- C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\ATL.DLL
- C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\InkObj.dll
- C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\IpsPlugin.dll
- C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\NETAPI32.dll
- C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\netutils.dll
- C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\profapi.dll
- C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\Secur32.dll
- C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\srvcli.dll
- C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\tabskb.dll
- C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\tipresx.dll
- C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\tiptsf.dll
- C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\USERENV.dll
- C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\WINSTA.dll
- C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\wkscli.dll
- C:\Windows\System32\apisetschema.dll
- C:\Windows\System32\atl.dll
- C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll
- C:\Windows\System32\clbcatq.dll
- C:\Windows\System32\cryptbase.dll
- C:\Windows\System32\cryptsp.dll
- C:\Windows\System32\dui70.dll
- C:\Windows\System32\duser.dll
- C:\Windows\System32\dwmapi.dll
- C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll
- C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll
- C:\Windows\System32\lpk.dll
- C:\Windows\System32\msctf.dll
- C:\Windows\System32\netapi32.dll
- C:\Windows\System32\netutils.dll
- C:\Windows\System32\oleacc.dll
- C:\Windows\System32\oleacchooks.dll
- C:\Windows\System32\oleaccrc.dll
- C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll
- C:\Windows\System32\profapi.dll
- C:\Windows\System32\psapi.dll
- C:\Windows\System32\RpcRtRemote.dll
- C:\Windows\System32\rpcss.dll
- C:\Windows\System32\rsaenh.dll
- C:\Windows\System32\samcli.dll
- C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll
- C:\Windows\System32\secur32.dll
- C:\Windows\System32\srvcli.dll
- C:\Windows\System32\sspicli.dll
- C:\Windows\System32\UIAutomationCore.dll
- C:\Windows\System32\userenv.dll
- C:\Windows\System32\usp10.dll
- C:\Windows\System32\uxtheme.dll
- C:\Windows\System32\version.dll
- C:\Windows\System32\winsta.dll
- C:\Windows\System32\wkscli.dll
- C:\Windows\System32\wmsgapi.dll
- C:\Windows\System32\xmllite.dll

If you need a quick way to check the existence of these files, create a text file with all these filenames (one on each line), and run the command `FOR /F %I IN (*filename*) DO @ECHO. & @ECHO %I & @DIR "%I" | find "Not"`

I do have the Tablet PC tools enabled, so a few of these DLLs might not be required if you don't have a Tablet PC. See what turns up when you look for these files anyway.

OSK also looks for a few CLSIDs and XML files as listed below:

- C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\fsdefinitions\main.xml
- C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\fsdefinitions\main\base.xml
- C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\fsdefinitions\oskmenu.xml
- C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\fsdefinitions\oskmenu\oskmenubase.xml
- C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\fsdefinitions\osknumpad.xml
- C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\fsdefinitions\osknumpad\osknumpadbase.xml
- C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\fsdefinitions\oskpred.xml
- C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\fsdefinitions\oskpred\oskpredbase.xml

Registry entries:

- HKCR\CLSID\{066D2323-D35A-4C15-AE22-F88F136C1613}
- HKCR\CLSID\{0A56CD6C-B45A-4A6C-A88C-3F42AC7BCED4}
- HKCR\CLSID\{3529B1D2-313A-4202-BD3E-5996B7E18A10}
- HKCR\CLSID\{632B0530-3CBF-44F4-BFDC-750A80D4B00A}
- HKCR\CLSID\{6A514DB9-3EC1-4F36-9F95-BC0B00152D0B}
- HKCR\CLSID\{884CFF4F-0BB0-4CAA-83BD-4FB9ECE938FA}
- HKCR\CLSID\{9FD4E808-F6E6-4E65-98D3-AA39054C1255}
- HKCR\CLSID\{E1D0AB13-2FE6-4DF0-8917-ED80CF0FEF6B}
- HKCR\CLSID\{E800E945-780D-48D3-89E7-D822EA18F0A2}
- HKCR\CLSID\{FF48DBA4-60EF-4201-AA87-54103EEF594E}
- HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Osk